# Sending Images throught sockets Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm doing a simple app to send images on Java, and I have some issues that I dont know how to solve it. The main problem is that when I send a large image (about 1000*600), the image is not fully received, I mean there is a part of the picture that is not like original picture. I think that is a overflow problem but I'm asking for other view point. Thank you !

originalImage : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgcZ2.jpg
receivedImage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ats3r.jpg

sendImage

```java
    public void sendFile(File inputFile) throws IOException {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1414);
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Conexion establecida");
            File f = inputFile;
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);

            byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();
            outputStream.write(size);
            outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println("Flushed: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            Thread.sleep(1);
            System.out.println("Closing: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            socket.close();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ButPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Client :

```java
try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1414);
                    while (true) {
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress() + " conectandose..." + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        byte[] sizeAr = new byte[1024];
                        inputStream.read(sizeAr);
                        int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();

                        byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];
                        inputStream.read(imageAr);

                        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr));
                        System.out.println("Received " + image.getHeight() + "x" + image.getWidth() + ": " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\imgTemp.jpg"));
                        File f = new File ("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\imgTemp.jpg");
                        System.out.println("Closing: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                        this.repaint();
                        serverSocket.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
```

Comment: How many bytes make your image? How many bytes do you actually read?

Comment: Your method of reading in data from the socket, `inputStream.read(sizeAr);`, is unreliable. You must read data in a loop, keeping track of how much is actually received, until you have read all the data. Or, much simply, take advantage of the `readFully()` method of `DataInputStream`.

Comment: You don't need to convert the file to an image. You don't need to convert the image to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You don't need the byte array of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Just copy the file directly to the socket in the usual way, with the standard Java copy loop. Your way you have the entire file in memory about three times and you are adding massive latency as well. Then at the other end all the same things apply. Just copy from the socket to the file. Examples abound here.